# XSL where statement

Tags: xslt, select, where-clause

I'm looking for some help with an XSL selector:

What I need is a selector that will show the **Title** of a different list where the **Document** of the same row matches the **Name** field.  If there is no entry, I will show a link to create a new one.  Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse
                       /Change_Types
                          /Rows
                             /Row
                                /@Document = @Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse
                                 /Change_Types
                                    /Rows
                                        /Row
                                           /@Document[
                                              /dsQueryResponse
                                                 /Change_Types
                                                    /Rows
                                                       /Row
                                                          /@Document = @Name
                                           ]"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Code to show link -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If anyone could point out where I'm going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That predicate will be always false because never a `@Document` attribute will have a `@Name` attribute. Please, post your XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:
A variable needed to be created for @FileLeafRef so it could be preserved to test against inside the for-each.

```
<xsl:variable name="document" select="@FileLeafRef"/>

<xsl:choose>
<!-- If there is an entry in the 'Tickets' list for this @FileLeafRef -->
<xsl:when test="/dsQueryResponse/Tickets/Rows/Row/@Document = $document">
    <!-- Show it here -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Tickets/Rows/Row">
        <xsl:if test="@Document = $document">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<!-- Else, show a link to add a new Ticket with the document auto-populated -->
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="addNewItemLink">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="'Tickets'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="document" select="@FileLeafRef"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of your source XML it's a complete guess, but I suspect that

```
@Document = @Name
```

should be

```
@Document = current()/@Name
```

on both occasions. Unless you really do want the `Document` and `Name` attributes of the same element to have the same value.